# React router v4 match path if not `/user`

Tags: javascript, regex, reactjs, react-router-v4

I have a case in react router v4:

```
<Route path="/:time?/:zone?" component={TimeComponent} />
```

However I don't want to render that `TimeComponent` if route is:

```
/user/userId123
```

As you can see above, the path matches `user` as `:time` and `userId123` as `:zone`.

My goal: I don't want path to match if route contains `/user`.

**I know** I can use `regex`, but how to specify that I dont want to match the path if contains `/user`?

Looking for help

Answer (score 2):

You can use switch from react router dom like this:

```
<Switch>
  <Route path="/user/:userId?" component={UserComponent} />
  <Route path="/:time?/:zone?" component={TimeComponent} />
</Switch>
```

With this it will match only one route at a time and you 2 param route is at the end. So using this approach you can catch /user route before time component route.

Please try this.